# How to display Firebase array items in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am building a Vue.js app that enables users to add items to an array already set in a Firebase doc. The function that adds items to the array in the database works fine. I want to return the items in the array as list items on the screen. Currently, however, the entire array container gets returned to the screen. How can I re-style this so that the array items render nicely as list items, without the container? Preferably with Vuetify. Thanks!

Template

```
<v-list class="elevation-1">
  <v-list-tile-content v-for="user in this.$store.getters.getUsers" :key="user.id" >
    <v-list-tile>
      {{ user.events }}
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list>
```

Method

```
    async addInput () {
      let finalInput = this.newInput
      let ref = await db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          doc.ref.update({'events': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(finalInput)})
        })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is what I was ultimately trying to accomplish. I reconfigured the addInput method to push inputted data as objects into the array. I then added a second loop two the template, which iterates through the items in the array user.events and returns them as list items. This worked! See below:

Template

```
<v-list class="elevation-1">
  <v-list-tile-content>
    <v-list-tile v-for="user in this.$store.getters.getUsers" :key="user.id">
      <v-list-tile v-for="newUser in user.events">
        {{ newUser.name }}
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list>
```

Method

```
async addInput () {
  let finalInput = this.newInput
  let ref = await db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      doc.ref.update({'events': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        'name': finalInput
      })
    })
  })
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `v-for` attribute should be declared inside the item elements, not the containing element.  To achieve this, move the `v-for` into the list item element like so:

```
<v-list class="elevation-1">
  <v-list-tile-content v-for="user in this.$store.getters.getUsers" :key="user.id">
    <v-list-tile v-for="event in user.events">
      {{ event }}
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately this didn't work though. The items in the array are children to "events". Is there something that I would need to add to ```{{ user.events }}``` to get the for loop to iterate through the array items instead of just the array as a whole?

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 Does this work for what you are looking for? Looping over each user to create a list of their events?

Comment: Yes, I already figured that out, but thank you for checking in. Much appreciated!